# How to start appium server using java on MAC OSX

Tags: java, macos, ios-ui-automation, appium-desktop

I am trying to start and stop the appium server by writing java code

the solutions that i found are old and doesnt work with the newer versions of appium.

I am using appium desktop v1.6.3 and server v1.8.1

i can open the desktop app programatically but not start the server.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer on how this works.

to start the server all you need is the below code

```
public static void startAppiumServer() {
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.9.0/bin/node"))
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .usingPort(4723).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1"));
    service.start();
    pause(25000);
    getLogger(logger, 'i', service.getUrl().toString(), null);
}
```

Note : you need to set the path = bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin in the run configuration of the project.

Comment: Hi this is an old question. But how and where do I set the path = bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin  would this go into my bash profile?  Also Service = Appium.... do I put that in the test class at the beginning.  Do you have any example code I can view?